# Looking for a tag-based file manager

Tags: software-recommendation, file-management

As most of users, I organize my files in folders using a standard file manager (Pantheon Files in elementary OS). However, I would like to also have another, quicker way to retrieve the files I need which makes use of **tags**.
To be more specific, I need to manage a large quantity of document files (pdf, doc, odt, etc.), so I'm not after a media library manager to organize my music and videos.

Can you recommend any apps that work well with elementary OS?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe try something like [Data Crow](http://www.datacrow.net/)?

I was never much satisfied with the "iTunes" approach to this, wherein you get an app to "Import" some "Library" of items that you can then tag and search and comment on.

So I always ended up hacking together my own solution. Except on Haiku or OSX > 10.8, which get tagging right (in my opinion).

## Poor man's solution

You can make a folder named "Tags" in your Home folder.

Then make some sub-folders within *for actual tags*.

And sym-link whatever you need there.
The act of sym-linking (or use [TMSU](http://tmsu.org/)) can be automated with a Contract for Files, so that "Tag this @Work" shows up in the context-menu.

That would work for a few tags, like "areas" in a GTD system, or "genres" in a music collection.

Back when I used Xfce with Thunar (the file manager), I used a Python script with a package I got out standard repos -- it displayed a simple dialog box. Let me see if I can possibly dig that up for you...

*Also if the devs are reading this, Thunar had a fantastic feature -- a "Templates" folder, which populated the "New File/Folder" context-menu.*

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I was looking for something more user-friendly, more like a graphical standalone app.

Comment: Maybe something like Data Crow?

Comment: Yeah, kinda. TagSpaces is the closest I've found so far. But I'll edit my question now to make it clearer.